# How to reply to a HR email asking for eligibility to work in the UK?

Tags: new-job, united-kingdom, relocation, visa

I applied for a job yesterday using LinkedIn from Pakistan to UK.

Now I got a reply from their HR Manager saying:

> Good Morning,
>
> Thank you for your recent application, please can you confirm your
>   eligibility to work in the UK and also please can you confirm when you
>   intend to be in the UK?

How can I reply to that email professionally? I never been to UK and I don't have visa of that country.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Employers must prevent illegal working in the UK by carrying out document checks on people before employing them to make sure they are allowed to work.](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/preventing-illegal-working-code-of-practice-for-employers)

They obviously want you to prove that you are allowed to work in the UK. It looks like *they* cannot do the job because you have not given them enough information. Or maybe they just want to shift the burden of answering that question to you - either because they want to see that you are willing to do the work to get the job, or because they get tons of foreign applications.

The easy way for you would be to ask what information they want.
The professional way for you would be to find out what the requirements are, then send them proof that you meet those requirements.

The first link should get you started; otherwise [Google "eligibility to work in the UK"](https://www.google.com/search?q=eligabilty+to+work+in+the+UK)

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful, i told the HR Manager, i would be needing sponsor. Thanks once again.